# SQL multiple start dates to end date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with the following format (which I cannot change)

```
ClientID  |  RefAd1  |  Cluster Start Date  |  Cluster End Date

100001    |   R1234  |    2014-11-01        |     
100001    |   R1234  |    2014-11-10        |  
100001    |   R1234  |    2014-11-20        |
```

What I would like to come out with is:

```
ClientID  |  RefAd1  |  Cluster Start Date  |  Cluster End Date

100001    |   R1234  |    2014-11-01        |     2014-11-10          
100001    |   R1234  |    2014-11-10        |     2014-11-20    
100001    |   R1234  |    2014-11-20        |     NULL
```

I've searched on here, and had many attempts myself, but just can't get it working.

I can't update the source table (or add another table into the database) so I'm going to do this in a view (which I can save)

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, been going round in circles with this for a day and a bit now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Self join to get next record

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Cluster Start Date])RNO,*
    FROM YOURTABLE
)
SELECT C1.ClientID,C1.RefAd1,C1.[Cluster Start Date],C2.[Cluster Start Date] [Cluster End Date]
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7946/2) to view result

**EDIT :**

To update the table, you can use the below query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Cluster Start Date])RNO,*
    FROM #TEMP
)
UPDATE #TEMP SET [Cluster End Date] = TAB.[Cluster End Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT C1.ClientID,C1.RefAd1,C1.[Cluster Start Date],C2.[Cluster Start Date] [Cluster End Date]
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1 
)TAB
WHERE TAB.[Cluster Start Date]=#TEMP.[Cluster Start Date]
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d66a/1) to view result

**EDIT 2 :**

If you want this to be done for `ClientId` and `RefAd1`.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Get current date and next date for each type of ClientId and RefAd1
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID,RefAd1 ORDER BY [Cluster Start Date])RNO,*
    FROM #TEMP
)
UPDATE #TEMP SET [Cluster End Date] = TAB.[Cluster End Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT C1.ClientID,C1.RefAd1,C1.[Cluster Start Date],C2.[Cluster Start Date] [Cluster End Date]
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1 AND C1.ClientID=C2.ClientID AND C1.RefAd1=C2.RefAd1
)TAB
WHERE TAB.[Cluster Start Date]=#TEMP.[Cluster Start Date] AND TAB.ClientID=#TEMP.ClientID AND TAB.RefAd1=#TEMP.RefAd1
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f74c5/1) to view result

If you want to do it only for `ClientId`, remove the conditions for `RefAd1`

Comment: that's perfect, many thanks!! +1 for the SQLFiddle website too, not seen that one before, going to be very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script if you just want the view you described:

```
CREATE VIEW v_name as
SELECT 
  ClientId, 
  RefAd1, 
  [Cluster Start Date], 
  ( SELECT 
      min([Cluster Start Date])
    FROM yourTable 
    WHERE 
      t.[Cluster Start Date] < [Cluster Start Date]
) as [Cluster End Date]
FROM yourtable t
```